# Retrieve html file from database once image is clicked in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel framework and I am looking to implement a feature so that when image on a page is clicked it loads it's source code and display that html file on the page. Image location and html file location are on the same database table. I am very new with ajax so could anyone tell me what function to use/ or give me an example so I can work on it. Thank you.

So this is how I want it to go:

Click on image>Request html from database>Display html in "" on the same page

View::

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Best programmer ever')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="{{asset('/js/template.js')}}" rel="javascript" type="text/javascript">
@section('content')
@endsection
        @section('template')

        <div class= "template_class">
          <a class="content-link" href="templates/template1.html"> 
        <img id = "image" src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
  </a>
</div>
        @show
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
   $('.content-link').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.content').load(this.href)
                    .fail(function()( alert('Oops...something went wrong')));
   });
});
```

DB Table::

```
Schema::create('templates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->string('file');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

DB Entry::

```
DB::table('templates')->insert(['image' => 'img/1.jpg', 'file' => 'templates/template1.html']);
```

Example of template which is to be displayed in a div::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Template 1</title>
  <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">Insert your content here</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "image ... loads it source code"? Huh? images (unless they're SVG) have no "source code".

Comment: This question is about as vague as it gets. You need to do some initial research yourself, then come back with a concrete attempt. Who knows, maybe you'll get it working without us!

Comment: None of this makes any sense. Provide some html structure and a far more concise explanation of what you are trying to do to that html

Comment: Basically I have a multiple html files and corresponding image for each one (template) and both of these are saved in a database. Once image 1 is clicked I want to display html 1, if I click on image 6 I want to display html 6.

Comment: study some ajax tutorials and javascript event handling

Comment: I have added some code and hopefully a better explanation of what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the image in an `<a>` and use the `href` to make request for correct html

```
<div class = "template_class">
  <a class="content-link" href="/path/to/get/html/{{ asset($template->id )}}"> 
        <img id = "image" src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Then in script

```
$(function(){
   $('.content-link').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.content').load(this.href)
                    .fail(function(){ alert('Oops...something went wrong');});
   });
});
```

Comment: Do I need to include any library for script to work and what if I don't want to be redirected to another page however insert that source code onto the same page let's say into <div class = "page">?

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: This is what I am getting but I want to display it on the same page

Comment: that url you showed was invalid. It's up to you to make sure the path is correct and the route exists for what you need

Comment: Yes I understand, however I do not want to be redirected into another page. I want to inject that html file onto the same page without reloading.

Comment: you won't be redirected. The event is canceled by `preventDefault()` unless you aren't implementing script properly or have errors thrown in browser console

Comment: Ok, I will now work with routes and path to make sure it work. Thanks for help

Comment: http://localhost/fyproject/public/templates/http://localhost/fyproject/public/1 This is the path I keep getting

Comment: clearly not creating it properly... you aren't setting the protocol if you are starting it with `"localhost/..."`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean something is wrong in how you create that `href`

Comment: <a class="content-link" href="templates/{{ asset($template->id )}}">  templates folder is where are my html files are

Comment: where is that in relation to the page url? Try making it absolute with a leading `'/'`

Comment: http://localhost/fyproject/public/templates/template1.html got it working however it is moving me to another despite using code you have provided

Comment: what errors are thrown in console? Is jquery loaded before the script tag for your code?

Comment: Yes it is loaded at the top of the page

Comment: Selector used may not match the elements

Comment: I have added my updated code in the main post, please have a look and see if I did anything wrong

Comment: needs to be in a `<script>` tag not `<link>`

Comment: It still loads it on another page for some reason

Comment: execute a log statement or alert in script to make sure it is loading

Comment: There must be something wrong as when I put alert in the script it is not executing

Comment: seems you need to get a better handle on setting paths. You should have access to something like `base_url` or whatever laravel uses

Comment: Can you help me with that? I would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: read up on how href , src and url's work. This is really basic basic stuff. I can't walk you through every single step of this

Comment: This is what I am getting from console now: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: i did put wrong wrong type of brace in `fail`...just fixed

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load(...).fail is not a function this is what I am getting

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.11.3 I am using this version